# Grails - How to verify my middleware(java app) is started before starting grails app

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I have one middleware application where all my Services(JMS and Webservices) running.

I have to check and validate middleware status before starting my (UI/Front end/client) grails application.

Is there any way to do that in my grails configurations or else where.

At present, I am running first middleware(One Bootstrap Main java class) and after grails app.

Answer (score 1):

You can ping the middleware app in Bootstrap.groovy:

```
  try {
    String response = new URL("http://my-middleware-app.com").text      
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //middleware app is not live
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think lukelazarovic's answer is what you need if you are looking a solution from within Grails. Another solution is to write a small shell script that tries to ping or curl your web service every few seconds and run yours grails app only when the middle ware is ready.